# Laravel added new event and listeners don't work

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

after updating `$listen` variable to

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserActivationCode' => [
        'App\Listeners\UserActivationCode\SendMailNotification',
        'App\Listeners\UserActivationCode\SendSMSNotification',
    ]
];
```

in `EventServiceProvider` and running

```
php artisan event:generate
```

command, events and listeners are created and i deploy them in past, now when i update that to:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserActivationCode' => [
        'App\Listeners\UserActivationCode\SendMailNotification',
        'App\Listeners\UserActivationCode\SendSMSNotification',
    ],
    [
        'App\Events\UserTracker' => [
            'App\Listeners\UserTracker\StoreUserTracker',
        ]
    ]
];
```

and run again the command, this event and listener don't create although i have to create this class manually in `Events` and `Listeners` folder, now this event don't work for me

test in route:

```
Route::get('/page/mahdi', function () {
    event(new \App\Events\UserTracker(\App\User::find(2),'hi',request()->ip()));
}
```

Event:

```
class UserTracker
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $user;
    public $action_name;
    public $user_ip;

    public function __construct(User $user, $action_name, $user_ip)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->action_name = $action_name;
        $this->user_ip = $user_ip;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

Listener:

```
use App\Events\UserTracker;
class StoreUserTracker
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(UserTracker $event)
    {
        dd($event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many square brackets there. Remove the ones around your `UserTracker` event:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserActivationCode' => [
        'App\Listeners\UserActivationCode\SendMailNotification',
        'App\Listeners\UserActivationCode\SendSMSNotification',
    ],
    'App\Events\UserTracker' => [
        'App\Listeners\UserTracker\StoreUserTracker',
    ],
];
```